# How to achieve update "batching" in factorybot for traits

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Say you have a Factory in FactoryBot, and say that factory has several traits for associations, and that each trait will need to update the model being created by the factory.  So, your main model is MainModel, and you have associations to A, B, C, D, etc...

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :main_model

  trait :with_a do
    after(:create) do |main_model|
      # Both sides refer to each other, so this must be done in after(:create).
      main_model.update(a_id: create(:a, main_model_id: main_model.id).id)
    end
  end

  trait :with_b do
    after(:create) do |main_model|
      # Both sides refer to each other, so this must be done in after(:create).
      main_model.update(b_id: create(:b, main_model_id: main_model.id).id)
    end
  end

  # More traits omitted...
end
```

Side note: We're not using ActiveRecord, so we cannot use the associations features built into FactoryBot.  Associations must be explicitly registered using a call to update on both sides of the association.  Even if I could, I'm not sure it would have any effect?

Now, if client code does the following:

`create(:main_model, :with_a, :with_b, :with_c, :with_d)`

This is going to result in the following writes to the db:

1. Create the main record
2. Create the A record that points to the main.
3. **Update the main record to point to the new A.**
4. Create the B record that points to the main.
5. **Update the main record to point to the new B.**
6. Create the C record that points to the main.
7. **Update the main record to point to the new C.**
8. Create the D record that points to the main.
9. **Update the main record to point to the new D.**

Of the above, Numbers 3, 5, 7, and 9 could all be done at the same time, at the very end, if I could simply build up a list of updates that are needed and find a "hook" that would allow me to do one more update after the final trait was applied, and factory bot was ready to return the final result to me.  I cannot figure out a way to do that, but the ability to do this would save thousands (probably tens of thousands) of DB writes across my spec suite.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: *"if I could simply build up a list of updates that are needed"* -- Have you considered using a `transient` attribute, for precisely this purpose? You could then define a single `after(:create)` block on the factory, which adds all of these associations based on the transient attribute's value. See: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes

Comment: I don't think that will work since I don't see how that gives me a single hook where all of the associations have been created such that I could do `main_model.update(a_id: a.id, b_id: b.id, c_id: c.id, d_id: d.id)`.  Traits do allow for transient attributes, but I'd still need an `after(:create)` block per trait and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Ok, I think the suggestion is actually to have all these registered as transient attributes on the `main_model` factory, and I could do that, I suppose, but then rather than be able to use this syntax `create(:main_model, :with_a, :with_b, ...)` I'd have to switch to this (providing a boolean value or something): `create(:main_model, with_a: true, with_b: true, ...)`.  Not horrible... for sure.  But not ideal, either.  Just muddies the syntax of traits a bit.  However, I do think that might achieve the goal.

Comment: Hang on, let me just sketch out what I had in mind as a proper answer below... It's a bit of a weird kludge, admittedly - but then this would normally be done in a much simpler way with `associations`, which you've explicitly stated cant't be used! (I'm not sure why that's the case, but no matter...)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a transient variable (I used `associations`, but call it whatever) - and use this to store all of the associated record IDs for a **single** record update in an `after(:create)` block.

Something like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :main_model do

    transient do
      associations { {} }
    end

    trait :with_a do
      associations { super.merge(a_id: create(:a, main_model_id: id).id) }
    end

    trait :with_a do
      associations { super.merge(b_id: create(:b, main_model_id: id).id) }
    end

    after(:create) do |main_model|
      main_model.update(associations)
    end
  end
end
```

Usage of the factory remains unchanged - e.g.

```
create(:main_model, :with_a, :with_b)
```

...So you shouldn't need to update any of the spec code.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is the original chicken and egg issue .  At the time the trait blocks are running, if it's before the `after(:create)` of the main model, I don't have an id for the main model, so I can't set it on the associated models.  If it's after the `after(:create)` of the main model, then it's too late and the main model won't be updated with the ids of the associated models.

Comment: The chicken and egg thing doesn't even come into play, unfortunately.  The traits can't access the associations hash of the parent.